# succesive image changes with jquery

Tags: jquery, image

Hi im making a mario like game for fun and i am stuck with making mario animate himself, as in make his arms/legs move. I have the code for it, and if i break it down it works, however I have so far failed to space it so that it is actually visible.
So far I have tried setTimeout and .delay however neither has worked

here is my js code at the moment with the .delay function.

```
function animateMario() {
    // cycles through other 4 images
    for (var i=1; i<5; i++) {
        $('#mario').attr('src', 'images/mario/mario_f_'+i+'.png').delay(100);
    }

    // returns to original image
    $('#mario').attr('src', 'images/mario/mario_f_0.png').delay(100);
};
```

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated :)
Thank you very much
If you have any questions please ask

Comment: Please post more of your code... not enough to go on. Better yet, create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I recommend if possible for you to create a sprite sheet and change the position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, delay does not work with all jQuery function, so you need to use interval. Try this code, it worked for me :

```
function animateMario() {
    var i = 1;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        $('#mario').attr('src', 'images/mario/mario_f_'+i+'.png');
        i++
        if(i==5){
            clearInterval(timer);
            $('#mario').delay(1000*(i+1)).attr('src', 'images/mario/mario_f_0.png');
        }
    }, 100)
};
```

Comment: i have the code on dropbox under the following link, this is including your additions but it still does not seem to work :/
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/crokydxqqwi9yt5/vwxr5U_Xkz
thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Edited my answer, take a look!

Comment: is it possible to have the animation only repeat once the previous is complete, as at the moment if the key is held down it completes the first animation correctly but then runs through the rest far to fast, is there a way to correct this? i tried getting the setInterval to run indefinetley until keyup but this didnt work, any suggestions?

Comment: I added a var complete and checked if it was complet before lauching the other animation. Check here : http://pastebin.com/fucpxC2E

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution. [Jsfiddle Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/HqKpe/3/)
*No delay, no jQuery required* :)
**See the simply code.**

```
 //select the element with the #mario ID
 var el_image = document.getElementById('mario');

 //array with the image
 var img = [
            'http://u.cubeupload.com/FollowTheWeb/1.png',
            'http://u.cubeupload.com/FollowTheWeb/2.png',
            'http://u.cubeupload.com/FollowTheWeb/3.png',
            'http://u.cubeupload.com/FollowTheWeb/4.png',
            'http://u.cubeupload.com/FollowTheWeb/5.png'
           ];


 //functionfor create the animation
 var i=0;
 function frame_switch ()
 {
   el_image.src = img[i]; //change the src attribute

     if(i > 3){  //is the index is 4 set i=0
         i=0;
     }else{i++; }
 }


 setInterval(frame_switch,150);  //repeat the function frame_swith() each 150ms
```

Comment: that looks good, but the reason i use jQuery is so that I can activate the animation on keydown

Comment: keydown is a JS event, jQuery does not create event, it create shortcut. object.onKeyDown = $().keydown()